# Connecting local database with android app using USBWebserver

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, localhost

I'm following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) tutorial to learn how to connect a local database through my android app. Since it's a guideline for me, I'm not following it completely, thus I won't copy everything and skip important parts or "challenge problems". Anyway, **the tutorial uses wampserver and I'm using usbwebserver** and, for now, I think this is the root of my problem.

My Json object returns null after request connection to the server.

This is my db_config.php:

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "root");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "usbw");
define('DB_DATABASE', "learning_android");
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");
?>
```

I'm using the same db_config from tutorial and that leads me to my first question:

to connect the page with the wampserver I need to type: `http://localhost/android_connect/test.php`

in the usbwebserver: `http://localhost:8080/android_connect/test.php`

so, **in my db_config.php should I use `define('DB_SERVER', "localhost:8080");`?** I'm not sure 'cause I already made this test and isn't working yet (maybe 'cause there is another error in parallel)

second and last question; In the tutorial he uses:

```
 private static String url_create_product = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/create_product.php";
```

to request the product creation (here is where the JSON object is becoming null), but I'm using:

```
private static String urlCreate =  "http://localhost:8080/android_connect/create_product.php";
```

I really didn't understand this part and probably I'm missing something here. He doesn't explain why his local link is ment to be `api.androidhive.info/android_connect/create_product.php`, where he defines this to sort of replace with a localhost link or anything like that, he just throws the link without explanation..then I ask, **Is my local request link wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my own answer but not succesful as I wanted.

Just don't use USBWebserver to operate this. Use [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/). I'm not sure why; I made every possible: combination of localhost, ports combination, code variables check and so on; Nothing solved the problem with usbwebserver.

For wamp, install it, make sure to make it accessful through the firewall for your network.

db_config.php is gonna look like this:

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "root"); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); 
define('DB_DATABASE', "learning_android"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); 
?>
```

by default user and password from wampserver is "root" and "*blank password field*".

your webservice url is gonna be:

`private static String urlCreate =  "http://10.0.2.2:80/YOU_FILES_PATH";`

which in my case is:

```
private static String urlCreate =  "http://10.0.2.2:80/android_connect/create_product.php";
```

also if you still find any problems or want to debug your php steps I would recommend to check my [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592716/is-there-a-way-to-debug-a-http-request-through-an-android-app-inside-eclipse)